# Keep Moving shapes and text in image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have these Elements that can be drag and resize all over the page.

```
    <!-- SVG elements -->

     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
         style="left:340px;top:200px;width:100px;height:200px;position:absolute;overflow:hidden" class="mySvgs">
         <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="100%" stroke="#008000" stroke-width="15" stroke-linecap="round" />
     </svg>

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
         style="left:460px;top:200px;width:100px;height:200px;position:absolute" class="mySvgs">
         <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" stroke="#8000FF" fill="#8080FF"
             rx="10" ry="10" stroke-width="5" />
     </svg>


     <!-- A paragraph -->
     <div style="left:860px;top:20px;width:100px;height:40px;position:absolute;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis" id="myParagraph">
        Test
      </div>

     <!-- A button -->
     <div style="left:260px;top:140px;width:100px;height:40px;position:absolute" id="myButton">
         <button style="left:0px;top:0px;width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute">ESP</button>
     </div>
```

I'm wanting to move the elements around inside the image and not be able to take them outside the image.

I've tried to use:
overflow: hidden

Comment: Can you provide fiddle for it.

Comment: @KiranPurbey: http://www.filedropper.com/test_169 <-- Here the index and javascript, i coudn't get it to add the javascript to fiddle. Was my first time using the site.